# Problem with a tie

Tags: piano, clefs, musescore, slurs

Why is MuseScore not creating the last tree notes in the bass clef. See the picture. Every time I try to put a quarter note above the half note it disappears.
 [image]

Answer (score 3):

Because the Eb3 is in a second voice. In the handbook they explain how to use multiple voices in a staff: https://musescore.org/en/handbook/voices

Now TBH, but I'm definitely no expert, I'd find it easier to read if the first Eb3 would be notated in the second voice too, since it alerts me something's coming up, and also since I won't need to hide the second voice rest as is done in your example. I.e. it would look like this:

[image]

Comment: In Musescore you can delete rests from any voice but the first, so that doesn't need to be a consideration.